# How to containerize database dependent services?

Tags: docker, architecture, dependencies, containers

Example: I got a microservice 'Alpha', which usually connects to 'http://localhost:3306/dbforalpha'. The service depends on that database. Now I want to containerize both, the database and the service. Of course the address of the database is changing, so that I can not even build an image for service 'Alpha'.

Now I am wondering how to deal with that problem? There must be a easier way than waiting until the database container is running to check it's ip:port. Do tools like kubernetes solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker comes with a `service discovery` mechanism (this is the basic term for how services know how to talk to each other), containers can be linked together, and you can use DNS to talk to them.

For example, your alpha service could  be linked to your database, and connect to `db:3306`, and Docker would set the necessary `/etc/hosts` entries in `alpha`, so it could resolve `db` to an IP.

Comment: Thank you! So, this `service discovery` seems to be the `docker-compose`-file? Guess `docker orchestration` is a term to describe these things of 'scaleable communication'.
As addon: after some google research it seems to be possible with `kubernetes` as well. At least this looks similar to a `docker-compose`-file: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service

Comment: Well, actually you don't need compose for this, you just need to put the containers on the same network using the `--network` option. But in terms of understandably and reproducibility, compose definitely simplifies this process. I'm not terribly familiar with Kubernetes, but it's definitely possible with Kubenernetes as well. Docker is definitely the simpler option for starting out.